# How to search numbers, letters as well as alphanumeric from an image?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, python-imaging-library, image-recognition, scipy.ndimage

what I want to do is a image recognition is

1. given image (5000 × 3500) dimension (white background)
2. the image will have geometric figure as well as alphanumerical
3. python will do the recognition of.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the `pytesseract` library will solve your problem.

First install the necessary libraries with the following pip command:
`pip install pytesseract, Pillow`

After you have successfully done this, you can run the following code.

```py
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```